# javascript strange behaviour in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, hoisting

I have the following java script code

```
var obj = (function(){
    var privateVariable1 = 5;

    function privateFunction(){
        alert(privateVariable1);
    }

    obj1 = {};
    obj1.publicVariable = privateVariable1;
    obj1.publicFunction = function(){
        privateFunction();
    }

    return obj1;

}());


alert(obj.publicFunction());
```

It alert's 5 and undefined. I did not understood why it alert's undefined also. Can anyone tell me why this behavior is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions return `undefined` by default in javascript, and you're not returning anything from `obj.publicFunction()` so it returns `undefined`, which is what is alerted when you do

```
alert(obj.publicFunction());
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `publicFunction` and `privateFunction` don't return a value.

Change to:

```
var obj = (function(){
    var privateVariable1 = 5;

    function privateFunction(){
        alert(privateVariable1);
        return privateVariable1;
    }

    obj1 = {};
    obj1.publicVariable = privateVariable1;
    obj1.publicFunction = function(){
        return privateFunction();
    }

    return obj1;

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is alerting 5 because in the `publicFunction` you call `privateFunction`, which will alert the `privateVariable1` (which is 5 in this case). Because you call your function in an alert, and the `publicFunction` doesn't return anything, it will return `undefined`.